# C# WPF MaterialDesign в XAML Toolkit DialogHost. Фоновое окно позади диалогового окна не затемняется

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design

Фоновое окно почему-то не затемняется при вызове DialogHost, то есть что диалог не является модальным. Заднее окно остается активным. Хотя в примере на Github все работает правильно. Не пойму где туплю.

XAML:

```
        <materialDesign:DialogHost x:Name="DH_getLoadingList" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        CloseOnClickAway="True"
        OverlayBackground="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueDarkBrush}" DialogTheme="Inherit" Grid.RowSpan="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
        <materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
            <StackPanel Margin="16" Orientation="Vertical">
                <Label Content="The row will be deleted." FontSize="16" />
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Content="OK" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}" IsDefault="True" Margin="0,8,8,0"  />
                    <Button Content="Cancel" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}" Margin="0,8,8,0" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
    </materialDesign:DialogHost>
```

код C#

```
    private void GettingFuelListCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DH_getLoadingList.IsOpen = true;                
    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MainDemo.Wpf/Domain/DialogsViewModel.cs

Comment: https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Dialogs